# What would cause a delay and in some cases skipping of client side calculations?

Tags: javascript, python, django, heroku, client-side

Hopefully I'm asking the right question:

I recently built a competition scoring app, eventually I'd like to get to the point where I learn how to build a websocket (I think that a good idea, no?) for  it but right now it works as follows. Users input scores into a form, the form is submitted to page where django takes the information and adds it to the database as follows:

```
 #Every time a form is submitted it goes through this
   #get results from the post
    number_of_judges = 15
    judge = request.POST.get("judge")
    round = request.POST.get("round")
    pk = request.POST.get("pk")
    event = request.POST.get("event")
    cat1 = float(request.POST.get("cat1")) * 5
    cat2 = float(request.POST.get("cat2"))* .5
    cat3 = float(request.POST.get("cat3"))*2.5
    cat4 = float(request.POST.get("cat4"))
    cat5 = float(request.POST.get("cat5"))*1.5

    total = sum([cat1, cat2, cat3, cat4, cat5])

    if round == "R1":
        inst = firstround_1.objects.get(pk =int(pk)) 
        scoring = score.objects.create(person = inst, judge = judge, cat1 = cat1, cat2 = cat2, cat3 = cat3, cat4 = cat4, cat5 = cat5, total = total, event = event) #this is here so i can go back and look at individual entries
        inst.score = float(inst.score) + ( total / number_of_judges )
        inst.Entry = inst.Entry + 1 #I put this here to track how many judges that submitted
        inst.save()
```

The problems I experienced was that some were delays, and some came in as duplicates, some seem to not have even made it into the final calculation of the persons score. There are on average 15 people inputting, I am using python-django 1.6.5.

Could this have been a wifi issue? (I was sharing wifi with a streaming service)

What are some ways I can prevent these problems?
I have since moved the app to heroku so that I can increase the dynos and such, would this actually help?

Comment: A lot of things could have gone wrong, but probably it's because of network issues. Delays: network issues on client/server side. Duplicates: clients hit refresh multiple time due to network issues. Disappeared records: again, network issues.